# 16.04 SERVER USING vsftpd using tls getting ECONNREFUSED

Tags: ftp, vsftpd, tls

I have 16.04 on a hosted server with a static IP.  I have the ufw off for the moment to get ftp working.  I configured vsftp, then I added the chroot capability.  It was working fine-sign in with a user and they are limited to their directory--singing in from a remote location.

Next, I am attempting to configure TLS to improve security.  I follow the instructions and generate the key, then turn on the options in the /etc/vsftpd.conf file (more details below)

I attempt to connect via Filezilla and I get the error 
Connection attempt failed with "ECONNREFUSED - Connection refused by server"

I see other similar questions, and I have tried the answers on similar questions with no result.

Following is what I added to the vsftp.conf to enable tls after successfully testing ftp without tls.

ssl_enable=YES

allow_anon_ssl=NO

force_local_data_ssl=YES

force_local_logins_ssl=YES

ssl_tlsv1=YES

ssl_tlsv2=NO

ssl_tlsv3=NO

rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem

rsa_private_key=/etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you verify that vSFTPd is actually lisgening on the specificed ports its' on?  You can check with `sudo netstat -tulpn | grep vsftpd` which should tell you if something (vsftpd) is listening on any ports, the "Connection Refused" usually indicates nothing is listening.

Comment: I tried your command, but I don't get a resulting list.  Maybe this is the issue, but it was working without the tls, so it must have been listening before?  If it is not listening I'm not sure how to resolve this.

Comment: Typically, this indicates your config isn't valid, or the service won't start.  Check the system logs for vsftpd error events; you can try with `sudo systemctl -l status vsftpd` as well to see if it gives any error messages.

Comment: What protocol do you use with FileZilla to connect to the server, i.e. please include the output from FileZilla into your question. My guess is that you are either trying to use SFTP (which is not the same as FTPS) or that you are using implicit FTPS (port 990) instead of explicit FTPS (port 21). See also [How To Configure vsftpd to Use SSL/TLS on a CentOS VPS](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-vsftpd-to-use-ssl-tls-on-a-centos-vps) which not only describes the vsftp config but also how to use it with FileZilla in detail.

Comment: For FileZilla I am using FTP explicit FTP over TLS.  I do not have a port selected, so it should detect a port, correct?  it is also set to passive. I am using an IP address as opposed to a machine name.

Comment: Indeed, it looks like it is failing on start.  Status=2, INVALIDARGUMENT.  The only difference between it working without TLS and not working with TLS are the lines I added above.  Is one of this wrong, or do I need to include something else?

Comment: Same problem here without solution...

Answer (score 1):

If anyone having the same issue, removing the following lines solved the problem for me:

```
ssl_tlsv1=YES
ssl_tlsv2=NO
ssl_tlsv3=NO
```